# How to connect two different servers in the same network

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql

i have to database server one with Postgresql and the other with MySQL on the same network.I established a connection from my machine to the server hosting mysql database and i want to connect between the other server hosting my application with the postgresql database but it fails. I allowed connection from all IP addresses in the machine hosting the mysql database by granting all access with the wildcard %.

Any help on what is preventing the application in the postgresql server machine from connecting to the one with the mysql server while the connection from local machine's XAMPP to the mysql in the other mysql server is successfully?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you try to connect via PHP?

Comment: Yes am connecting via PHP,the application is in codeigniter trying to connect to the MySQL server

Comment: Did you run flush privileges command ?

Comment: yes i ran that command and that is why i was able to connect from my local machine to the the server hosting mysql,but when i try to connect to the MySQL server from the other server with postgresql there is is no sucess

Comment: You should change bind-address property in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file to 0.0.0.0 or the specific ip

Comment: I have even tried to specify the server hosting the postgresql apart from using % which allows any IP address with no success

Comment: Did you update `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file?